# Filtered Lookup Field for more then one element

Tags: lookup-column, filter

How could I do filtered lookup field for more then one element? I make for one Element by this link:

http://howididit-sharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/04/filtering-lookup-columns.html

But how could I done for more element say about twenty elements ?

Answer (score 2):

To filter lookup field you can use [SPFilterDropdown](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPFilterDropdown) function of SPServices. This function allows you to filter lookup column using CAML Query against source list. All you have to do is [download](http://spservices.codeplex.com/releases/view/92552) the SPServices js file and use it. One more thing jQuery reference is also needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But I must do with Sharepoint solution on the Box, not out of Box.

Comment: Should I install any adons on it, or I must add SPServices only to head ?

Comment: Where Should I add the JQuery ?

Comment: Ok I Conected them but how use a filter ? Please help.

Comment: you have to add reference to jquery and SPServices on the form/page on which you want filtered lookup column. Just download the two js file and upload in a document library of SP. Then provide link to them in the required page. Make sure jquery is referenced before SPServices. For more details check this link http://sympmarc.com/2012/05/11/using-spfilterdropdown-to-reorder-options-in-a-dropdown-on-a-sharepoint-form/